# What is the meaning of ObjectRemoved (JaVers) type of change?

Tags: auditing, javers

JaVers users,

I try to understand the basics of a JaVers compare, but can't figure it out!

I've created a very basic MyObject class like below:

```
public class MyObject {

    @Id
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String remark;

    public MyObject() {
        id=-1;
        name = "";
        remark = "";
    }

    public MyObject(int id)
    {
        this.id = id;
        name = "";
        remark = "";
    }

    public MyObject(int id, String name, String remark) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.remark = remark;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getRemark() {
        return remark;
    }

    public void setRemark(String remark) {
        this.remark = remark;
    }
}
```

I create two MyObject's like:

```
MyObject firsto = new MyObject(1);
MyObject secondo = new MyObject(2);
```

Next I do a:

```
Diff diff = javers.compare(firsto,secondo);
System.out.println(diff);
```

The output looks like:

```
Diff:
1. NewObject{globalId:'mypackage.MyObject/2'}
2. ObjectRemoved{globalId:'mypackage.MyObject/1'}
```

My question is what is the exact meaning of ObjectRemoved in this output?
Was not able to find any documentation on this, sorry!

Regards,
Gerard

Answer (score 0):

NewObject means that an object exists only on the right side of a diff. ObjectRemoved - only on the left. Since you have mapped your class as Entity, `MyObject(1)` and new `MyObject(2)` are two different objects so you cant compare them. Try to map MyObject as ValueObject